# I accidentally down-voted an answer that I meant to up-vote, and now I can't change it

Tags: support

Last month, I accidentally clicked down-vote on a very useful answer that I had meant to up-vote.

I didn't realize my error until today.

Now, when I try to correct the mistake, I get the message, "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Would someone please help me remedy this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an edit to the answer. You have >2k rep, so you can edit it directly. Once edited, you're free to change your vote.

Comment: Ok. Fortunately there was a minor spelling error in the answer, so my edit was actually useful.